# Wifi Card prevents PC from shutting down

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I have got an Gigabyte GC-WB867D-I and a Z170-HD3P.

When i shut down Win10 the computer automaticly restarts.
I have tured of WoL, FastBoot, and much more, but it doesn't work, and i unchecked this wake up the pc tick.
I also updated all drivers.

Might this be an hardware issue?

Comment: You wrote "Wifi Card prevents PC from shutting down". So if you remove that Wi-Fi card, shutdown works normally again?

Comment: Yes, I already returned it.

Comment: You returned it where?

Comment: I handed it back because of a hardware error.

Comment: Ok, if you know an answer now, maybe you can consider adding it as regular answer below.